# How do I add functionality to a UI made in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have made a pretty little UI on storyboard but I'm quite new to XCode and Objective C (coming over from Java) and I'm having some trouble adding functionality.  I know that I should make a subclass of UITableViewController (storeTableViewController) and set the class of the storyboard controller to that.  The problem is that when I do that all my hard work in the storyboard is erased, and I can see where the code is conflicting with the showing of my UI (for instance, the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection returns 0 always), and I think that with enough time and patience I could program the UI, but is there any way that I can use all this work that I've done on the storyboard and still be able to add functionality?  I want to set a text box at the top to be the first responder as well as be able to change an image and labels on command programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use IBOutlets. Connect the StoryBoard UI Object to IBOutlets and you can modify the properties of the UI objects from the code
You can declare IBOutlet link this

```
 IBOutlet type variableName
```

Check this tutorial video which will help you a lot.

[Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1VSqaRL8xc)

Answer (score 0):

I use the storyboard as a canvas. I plug in the outlets that I want and all the little details and then I go around and built the classes. That being said, you need to declare a urtext field outlet (depending to what you want it to do) then add the delegates necessary and allow it to perform on selector. Then you can declare the function. Linking it in storyboard is easy by control and drag.as far the image you can use an uiimage and declare its function and how it changes depending to what the changes are the code varies. My suggestion is to take screen shot of your storyboard and post it with your question so I/ we can help you with the code. But as far as your question goes I hope this answer satisfies you. Happy coding.:)

Comment: I tried to post an image but apparently I'm too new to stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems you already selected the other answer as the correct one so there is no need of posting an image. I'm glad you found the right answer to your question and happy coding.:)